# JavaScript convertendo data errada

Tags: javascript, data

Estou precisando converter data do tipo `yyyy-mm-dd` para `dd/mm/yyyy`.
Para isso,estou usando a função em JavaScript:

```
  data_formatar = new Date("2019-01-15")
  data = data_formatar.toLocaleDateString('pt-BR');
```

Saberiam me informar porque o retorno acima está trazendo 14/01/2019 e não 15/01/2019? E como resolver esse problema?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Esse código está trazendo o dia anterior, pelo fato de você estar passando apenas a data, sem informar a hora.

Assim, a data fica da seguinte forma: `15/01/2019 00:00:00`.

E como o timezone padrão do Brasil, tem GMT -3 horas, como provavelmente deve estar configurado na sua máquina, é subtraída 3 horas da hora que ele obteve, ficando agora `14/01/2019 21:00:00`.

Para corrigir isso você pode fazer das seguintes formas:

- Passando o timeZone padrão:

```js
data_formatar = new Date("2019-01-15")
  .toLocaleDateString('pt-BR', {timeZone: 'UTC'});
console.log(data_formatar); // 15/01/2019
```

- Ou informando também a hora:

```js
data_formatar = new Date("2019-01-15 00:00:00")
  .toLocaleDateString('pt-BR');
console.log(data_formatar); // 15/01/2019
```

Links úteis:
https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Sendo um pouco pedante: na verdade o locale só controla o formato (se é d/m/y, y-m-d, etc). Mas os **valores** de data e hora vêm do timezone do browser, tanto que se fizer `new Date("2019-01-15").toLocaleDateString('ja-JP')` (locale do Japão), o valor do dia continua 14, mesmo que no Japão a data equivalente seja 15 (pois eles estão em UTC+9) - só vai mudar o formato, os valores não. E dependendo da região do Brasil, não necessariamente vai ser UTC-3: se for regiões com horário de verão, em janeiro é -2 (sudeste) ou -3 (centro oeste), se for no nordeste é -3, mas no Amazonas é -4, etc :-)

Comment: Sim, verdade amigo. Acabei confundindo `locale` com `timeZone`. Obrigado pelo alerta!

Answer (score 4):

Quando você passa uma string neste formato para o [construtor de `Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Parameters), ele usa a mesma regra do método [`Date.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse#Using_Date.parse()).

Neste caso, a string contém somente dia, mês e ano no formato [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), e esta informação é completada com o horário igual a meia-noite, em [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC).

O problema é que [`toLocaleDateString`](http://toLocaleDateString) usa o timezone do browser (que não necessariamente será o mesmo que UTC) para obter os valores do dia, mês e ano. Meu browser, por exemplo, está usando o fuso-horário brasileiro (Horário Oficial de Brasília).

E como 15 de janeiro de 2019, à meia-noite em UTC, corresponde à 14 de janeiro de 2019, às 22h no horário de Brasília, ocorre esta diferença (normalmente o horário de Brasília está 3 horas atrás do UTC, mas em janeiro de 2019 estava em horário de verão, por isso estava apenas 2 horas a menos, e dependendo da região em que você está, a diferença com relação a UTC pode ter outro valor - de qualquer forma, o timezone do seu browser é algum que está algumas horas antes de UTC, daí a diferença).

Algumas soluções (além de setar o timezone para UTC, como já sugerido nas outras respostas):

---

Adicionar o horário (feio, mas [sugerido pela própria documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse#Using_Date.parse()) e funciona, pois aí ele passa a considerar meia-noite no timezone do browser):

```js
let d = new Date("2019-01-15T00:00");
console.log(d.toLocaleDateString('pt-BR')); // 15/01/2019
```

Lembrando de colocar a letra `T` antes do horário, conforme o formato definido pela [norma ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

---

Fazer o *parsing* manualmente:

```js
let [ano, mes, dia] = '2019-01-15'.split('-').map(v => parseInt(v));
let d = new Date(ano, mes - 1, dia);
console.log(d.toLocaleDateString('pt-BR'));

// Ou, caso o seu browser não seja compatível com ES6:
let partes = '2019-01-15'.split('-');
ano = parseInt(partes[0]);
mes = parseInt(partes[1]);
dia = parseInt(partes[2]);
d = new Date(ano, mes - 1, dia);
console.log(d.toLocaleDateString('pt-BR'));
```

Lembrando que nesta API janeiro é zero, fevereiro é 1, etc, então tem que subtrair 1 do mês ao passar para o construtor de `Date`.

---

Usar uma biblioteca como o [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/):

```js
let d = moment("2019-01-15");
console.log(d.format("DD/MM/YYYY"));
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Ou, para usar o formato específico de acordo com o locale, use o `moment-with-locales`:

```js
moment.locale('pt-BR'); // setar o locale para Português
let d = moment("2019-01-15");
console.log(d.format("L"));
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

[Faltou lembrar do timeZone](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse):

```
data_formatar = new Date("2019-01-15").toLocaleDateString('pt-BR', {timeZone: 'UTC'});
console.log(data_formatar);
```

Answer (score 0):

Opa Willian, isso acontece devido ao fuso horário, por padrão o fuso horário é o UTC, ao mudar a localização `toLocaleDateString` assume o fuso horário local. Por você não definir horário ele assume que é meia noite e diminui as horas, faça da seguinte maneira pra não acontecer esse problema:

```
data_formatar = new Date("2019-01-15")
data = data_formatar.toLocaleDateString('pt-BR', {timeZone: 'UTC'});
```